# How to send custom http response code back from spring cloud functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, spring-cloud-function

I was using Spring Cloud Functions with azure...but could not figure out how using Spring cloud function I can send a custom HTTP code back in response.... as we can do in ResponseEntityAs of now I do not see a way of doing that. let's say after validation I want to throw a 400 BAD REQUEST error in the response or add some specific parameter in the response header, how do I do that.

Comment: At the moment we provide a delegation model for Azure functions. There seem to be a lot of error handling [scenarios and approaches](https://hackernoon.com/reliable-event-processing-in-azure-functions-37054dc2d0fc) that you can benefit from natively in Azure

Comment: Also, as described in [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java) you can define your function as `@FunctionName("myFunction") public HttpResponseMessage myFunction(..)` effectively giving you full control over HttpResponse.